# With Google Maps API, Marker properties can be assigned with Object.values() but not with a for..in statement, why is this occurring?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have 2 identical JS scripts save one method. These methods differ in that script #1 accesses object properties using a for..in statement whereas script #2 uses the object property method for access.

The only difference I can find between these two is that a for-in loop enumerates properties in the prototype chain as well.

How does this difference in property access cause one script to not work with the Google Maps API, whereas a change in the method causes the second script to work properly, rendering markers.

**Method #1:**

```
var baMarkers = function getMarkers(siteDatabase) {
  for (var site in siteDatabase) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(site.lat, site.lng),
      map: bayarea,
      title: site.position
    });
    var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
      content: site.position,
    });
    marker.addListener('click', function() {
      site.infoWindow.open(map, site.marker);
    });
  };
};
```

**Method #2:**

```
  Object.values(siteDatabase).forEach(site => {
    const marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(site.lat, site.lng),
      map: bayarea,
      title: site.position,
    });
    var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
      content: site.position,
    });
    marker.addListener('click', function() {
      site.infoWindow.open(map, site.marker);
    });
  });
};
```

**jsfiddle**

[script #1](http://jsfiddle.net/nomad343/se9d62ue/35/)

[script #2](https://jsfiddle.net/nomad343/9yudek2h/10/)

Comment: Please reflect in title this is about Google Maps.

Comment: You aren't doing the same thing in both fiddles.  The one that doesn't work defines a function `getMarkers`, but never calls it (therefore no markers).

Comment: If I do call it though the problem persists, unless I am doing something I don't understand as a JS novice. http://jsfiddle.net/nomad343/se9d62ue/41/

Comment: [fiddle calling function](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/se9d62ue/37/)